# Search for multiple values in one parameter

Tags: rest, swagger-ui

I am new to REST API and I guess have quite a simple question. I am trying to get data from multiple companies from WEB service REST API (Swagger).

in GET option, I have two required parameters: the first is country, and the second is the firm's unique identifier.

If I set country and one unique identifier, it works well. I have many firms I have to get data for, so I wonder, is it possible to put multiple entries for the firm's identifier.

I tried separate with (; , &) but always receive an error.

Does anyone have a solution on how to search for multiple firms at the same time?

Comment: If the API designers haven't built in the affordances to support multiple arguments, there's nothing you can do from the outside to make it happen anyway.

Comment: Ask the API vendor.